# What is the function time out limit at Alibaba Function Compute?

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud, faas

I'm doing some research for my thesis in the faas field. I want to compare the faas provider...

Can anybody tell me what the maximum is that a function can run on alibaba function compute?

Couldn't find anything on google about it.

Comment: Nowadays it is 86400 seconds (24 hours) both for Elastic Instances, Performance Instances, and GPU Instances. See https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/179379.html?spm=5176.fcnext.0.0.1b9a78c8ZYzlBm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 600 seconds (10 minutes) according to this [doc](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/51907.htm).

> Maximum execution duration per request: 600s